# apparent strangeness using subroutine with the multiplication operator

Tags: perl

Please could you explain this *apparently* inconsistent behaviour to me:

```
use strict;
sub a { 2 + 2 };
print 2 * a(); # this prints: 8
print a() * 2; # this prints: 8
print 2 * a;   # this prints: 8
print a * 2;   # this prints: 4
```

Thanks for answers, both very helpful - I learned a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the last example, the expression is parsed as `a(*2)` which calls `a` with the glob argument `*2` which is the short name of the package variable `*main::2`

If you want `a` to be parsed as a function that takes no arguments, you need to declare it like this:

```
sub a () {2 + 2}
```

Then perl will parse the statement as you expected.  In fact, if you write it like this, perl will detect that it is a constant function, and will inline `4` in every place where `a` would have been called.

Comment: oh that's like how JavaScript won't accept function a{... it has to be function a() {... as i found out when i went here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onblur. so *2 or *main::2 is the glob that is connected to the backreference scalar $2?

Comment: Not exactly, in JavaScript, the `()` is a mandatory part of the signature.  In Perl, the prototype is optional.  When not given, Perl defaults to `(@)` which means that the subroutine is parsed as a list operator (meaning it can take an unlimited number of arguments). This is why your example saw `*2` as an argument.

Comment: very interesting Eric. so sub a{2+2} is the same as sub a(@) {2+2}

Comment: A subroutine declared without a prototype has an implicit `(@)` prototype which means that it is parsed as a list operator. See here for more details: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html

Answer (score 12):

Deparse reveals that you are passing a glob to a in the last one:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse,-p
use strict;
sub a { 2 + 2 };
print 2 * a(); # this prints: 8
print a() * 2; # this prints: 8
print 2 * a; # this prints: 8
print a * 2; # this prints: 4
__END__
sub a {
    use strict 'refs';
    4;
}
use strict 'refs';
print((2 * a()));
print((a() * 2));
print((2 * a()));
print(a(*2));
```

Using parens on your subroutine calls is a good thing...